# Visual Basic .Net Public Function decodes a one line procedure before it gets executed

Tags: vb.net, base64

I encountered an issue with Function and Procedure while experimenting with some code, as below:

```
    Module mod1
        Class ExampleApp

            Dim textvalue as String = "dGhpcyBpcyBhbiBleGFtcGxlIG9mIGEgdGV4dC4="
            Dim string1 as String = "Convert.FromBase64String(input)"

            Public Function DecodeB64(ByVal input As String) As String

                Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(string1)

            End Function

        End Class
    End Module
```

The question is, is it possible to encode the statement inside the Public Function before it gets executed?

I have seen some cases where they implemented it on PHP Scripts, where the whole script is encoded before it gets executed. I have tried my best in applying the same concept by storing "Convert.FromBase64String(input)" to a string variable but I'm encountering an issue like this:

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-Dimensional array of
>   Byte'

When I don't apply this concept, the text in base64 gets decoded smoothly. My main goal is that I want to obscure the statement or group of statements as much as possible. What seems to be the problem in this Error?

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String` returns a Byte array. You are trying to stuff it into a String. No can do.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes below in the example code:

- First, you should know that [`Convert.FromBase64String()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns
  `Byte()` array, hence you can't assign it to string variable/field.
- Second, [`Encoding.GetString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332098(v=vs.71).aspx) requires `Byte()` array as parameter,
  but you're passing string to it, hence `InvalidCastException` occurred.

The correct usage of them should be like this:

```
Public Function DecodeB64(ByVal input As String) As String

    ' make sure the input string is Base64 formatted
    Dim bytearray As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(input)

    ' decoding from byte array
    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytearray)

End Function

' usage
Dim textvalue as String = "dGhpcyBpcyBhbiBleGFtcGxlIG9mIGEgdGV4dC4="
Dim result As String = DecodeB64(textvalue)
```

Working example: [.NET Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PhjVwq)